# Building android app with unity gives black screen

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, opengl-es

I am trying to build a project to android but suddenly it doesnt work anymore. I just get a black screen and this log in logcat. It has been working for years on the appstore and the live version shows a black screen aswell.. In this build im just building an empty scene with a green background and it is still black when it plays

`04-09 12:34:18.101 24372 24399 D Unity   : Started listening to [0.0.0.0:55461] 04-09 12:34:18.137 24372 24399 D Unity   : InitializeScriptEngine OK (0x73f267cfc0) 04-09 12:34:18.137 24372 24399 D Unity   : PlayerConnection already initialized - listening to [0.0.0.0:55461] 04-09 12:34:18.151 24372 24399 D Unity   : PlayerInitEngineNoGraphics OK 04-09 12:34:18.151 24372 24399 D Unity   : AndroidGraphics::Startup window =  0x7340241010 04-09 12:34:18.151 24372 24399 D Unity   : [EGL] Attaching window :0x7340241010 04-09 12:34:18.163 24372 24399 D Unity   : [EGL] Request: ES 3.1+AEP RGB0 000 0/0 04-09 12:34:18.163 24372 24399 D Unity   : [EGL] Checking ES 3.1 support... 04-09 12:34:18.165 24372 24399 D Unity   : [EGL] ES 3.1 support detected 04-09 12:34:18.165 24372 24399 D Unity   : [EGL] Found: ID[5] ES 3.1+AEP RGB16 565 0/0 04-09 12:34:18.165 24372 24399 D Unity   : [EGL] Request: ES 3.1+AEP RGB0 000 0/0 04-09 12:34:18.165 24372 24399 D Unity   : [EGL] Found: ID[5] ES 3.1+AEP RGB16 565 0/0 04-09 12:34:18.165 24372 24399 D Unity   : [EGL] Request: ES 3.0 RGBA32 8888 0/0 04-09 12:34:18.165 24372 24399 D Unity   : [EGL] Found: ID[1] ES 3.0 RGBA32 8888 0/0 04-09 12:34:18.167 24372 24399 D Unity   : ANativeWindow: (2000/1200) RequestedResolution: (0/0) RenderingResolution: (0/0) EGLSurface: (2000/1200) 04-09 12:34:18.173 24372 24399 D Unity   : Renderer: Mali-G72 04-09 12:34:18.173 24372 24399 D Unity   : Vendor:   ARM 04-09 12:34:18.173 24372 24399 D Unity   : Version:  OpenGL ES 3.2 v1.r38p1-01bet0-mbs2v41_0.49c562ebe5faf1a47d2b8e7043cf01b0 04-09 12:34:18.173 24372 24399 D Unity   : GLES:     3 04-09 12:34:18.173 24372 24399 D Unity   :  GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_ARM_rgba8 GL_ARM_mali_shader_binary GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_EXT_read_format_bgra GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_required_internalformat GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_OES_mapbuffer GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_rg GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_EXT_shadow_samplers GL_OES_texture_compression_astc GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_hdr GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_sliced_3d GL_KHR_debug GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_OES_texture_3D GL_EXT_texture_storage GL_EXT_multisampled_render_ 04-09 12:34:18.173 24372 24399 D Unity   : to_texture GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture2 GL_OES_surfaceless_context GL_OES_texture_stencil8 GL_EXT_shader_pixel_local_storage GL_ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch GL_ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch_depth_stencil GL_ARM_mali_program_binary GL_EXT_sRGB GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_R8 GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_RG8 GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent GL_OES_texture_storage_multisample_2d_array GL_OES_shader_image_atomic GL_EXT_robustness GL_EXT_draw_buffers_indexed GL_OES_draw_buffers_indexed GL_EXT_texture_border_clamp GL_OES_texture_border_clamp GL_EXT_texture_cube_map_array GL_OES_texture_cube_map_array GL_OES_sample_variables GL_OES_sample_shading GL_OES_shader_multisample_interpolation GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks GL_OES_shader_io_blocks GL_EXT_tessellation_shader GL_OES_tessellation_shader GL_EXT_primitive_bounding_box GL_OES_primitive_bounding_box GL_EXT_geometry_shader GL_OES_geometry_shader GL_ANDROID_extension_pack_es31a GL_EXT_gpu_sh 04-09 12:34:18.173 24372 24399 D Unity   : ader5 GL_OES_gpu_shader5 GL_EXT_texture_buffer GL_OES_texture_buffer GL_EXT_copy_image GL_OES_copy_image GL_EXT_shader_non_constant_global_initializers GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_unpack_subimage GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_YUV_target GL_OVR_multiview GL_OVR_multiview2 GL_OVR_multiview_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_KHR_robustness GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior GL_EXT_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_OES_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_EXT_protected_textures GL_EXT_buffer_storage GL_EXT_external_buffer GL_EXT_EGL_image_array GL_ARM_texture_unnormalized_coordinates GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch 04-09 12:34:18.179 24372 24399 D Unity   : OPENGL LOG: Creating OpenGL ES 3.2 graphics device ; Context level  <OpenGL ES 3.1 AEP> ; Context handle -1198367616 04-09 12:34:18.180 24372 24399 D Unity   : [EGL] Attaching window :0x7340241010 04-09 12:34:18.184 24372 24399 D Unity   : Requested framebuffer: resolution[2000x1200], rgba[8/8/8/8], depth+stencil[on], samples[1] 04-09 12:34:18.184 24372 24399 D Unity   : Created framebuffer: resolution[2000x1200], rgba[8/8/8/8], depth+stencil[24/8], samples[0] 04-09 12:34:18.184 24372 24399 D Unity   : [EGL] Attaching window :0x7340241010 04-09 12:34:18.184 24372 24399 D Unity   : Initialize engine version: 2018.4.9f1 (ca372476eaba) 04-09 12:34:18.335 24372 24399 D Unity   : PlayerInitEngineGraphics OK 04-09 12:34:18.339 24372 24399 D Unity   : Found 26 native sensors 04-09 12:34:18.342 24372 24399 D Unity   : Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.002394 / 0.00s ; ICM42605M Accelerometer / TDK Invensense 04-09 12:34:18.343 24372 24399 D Unity   : Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.002394 / 0.00s ; ICM42605M Accelerometer / TDK Invensense 04-09 12:34:18.351 24372 24399 D Unity   : SetWindow 0 0x7340241010 04-09 12:34:18.351 24372 24399 D Unity   : [EGL] Attaching window :0x7340241010 04-09 12:34:20.403 24372 24399 D Unity   : UnloadTime: 1.192000 ms 04-09 12:34:20.411 24372 24399 D Unity   : UUID: b50a556472eb151f => 95e54368980bfd2aff5fbafa73eafc28 04-09 12:34:20.434 24372 24399 D Unity   : Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.002394 / 0.00s ; ICM42605M Accelerometer / TDK Invensense 04-09 12:34:20.445 24372 24399 D Unity   : Choreographer available: Enabling VSYNC timing 04-09 12:34:50.886 24372 24372 I Unity   : onPause 04-09 12:34:54.888 24372 24372 W Unity   : Timeout while trying to pause the Unity Engine. 04-09 12:34:58.939 24372 24372 W Unity   : Timeout while trying detaching primary window. 04-09 12:34:58.974 24372 24372 I Unity   : windowFocusChanged: false`

Can someone make any sense of this?

Thank you

Comment: Does this happen on different devices? Different GPUs (this is Mali-G72, driver r38p1)? What's changed since it worked? Testing on a different device, or changed version of Unity (which version is it?), or changed version of OpenGL ES (this is targeting 3.1 if I read correctly?), or anything else changed?

Comment: I have tried on 3 different devices and many different settings. The wierd thing is the app i released a long time ago also has a black screen when downloaded from the store.. 
I spend so long time playing around with different settings and making a blank sceen  with yellow background in the same project. but its just black when builded nowmatter what.

Comment: Its unity version 2018.4.9f1 it has so many plugins that is breaks if updated

Comment: which devices fail (with what drivers on them)?  Are they different devices to what you previously used when it worked? Can you find a device that did/does work with the old version? Start from something that did/does work (old app version, old phone) as 'known good' and work out what has changed. (New CPU/GPU/Android version/drivers etc could all have broken it, if you've made no changes to the project/Unity version+plugins)